# Unable to receive cURL data through PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal

Ok, I'm trying to integrate Paypal with my website. It's asking me to make a cURL request to a restful web service. I've managed to get the php looking good. I know it's basic, but it should be working.

```
if(etc...){
    $params = ['USER'=>'me', 
        'PWD'=>'mypassword', 
        'SIGNATURE'=>'SIG', 
        'METHOD'=>'SetExpressCheckout', 
        'VERSION'=>'93', 
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=>'SALE', 
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'=>10, 
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'=>'GBP', 
        'RETURNURL'=>'http://returnPage.html', 
        'CANCELURL'=>'http://returnPage.html'];

   $defaults = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.sandbox.paypal.com', 
        CURLOPT_POST => true, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params), 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1,);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $defaults);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $token = $output;
}

echo $token
```

The problem is that the returned output is false for some reason and network tab on my browser says the request to the php file takes a long time. Actually when testing all other code works, but php file doesn't return any data. If I leave it for a while sometimes it returns false instead of the cURL data.

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

EDIT:

When testing my credentials by cURLing from command prompt everything works fine. There are no errors in my PHP is there a way of diagnosing why the cURL command isn't working.

EDIT 2:

The command needed to get a response is

```
curl -s --insecure  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp  -d  "USER=users&PWD=pass=Abg0gYcQyxQvnf2HDJkKtA-p6pqhA1k-KTYE0Gcy1diujFio4io5Vqjf&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=78&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&cancelUrl=http://www.example.com/cancel.html&returnUrl=http://www.example.com/success.html"
```

I don't know what the --insecure bit is I'm thinking it's something to do with security but I have no idea how to set that as an option in php.

Comment: in the code above your reference http://api.sandbox.paypal.com - that should be https!

Comment: Do you thin its wise to post your pass on a site with millions of users?Add these lines after curl_exec `$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

 print_r($info);` Edit your question with the result

Comment: Also the equivalent in php for --insecure is  `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1,);`

this line shoul be

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> 1);`

**Add `=>` and remove `,` after 1**

Change url protocol to `https` and add option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>1`.

Comment: I've changed it but it's not that. I must have made a mistakeon this one. I've tried a couple of variations and always the same.

Comment: @TomAlbanese does the paypal application link you provided is correct? I think this is the sandbox  app link https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Comment: It works when I run from command prompt and I got it directly from the paypal website, under my app credentials.

Comment: @TomAlbanese what is the protocol? https or http?

Comment: This is what I don't know, the example is https. So would I need to set some other php options

Comment: sure, change url protocol to https and try again

Comment: The problem is with the app link, I was testing with the endpoint in the example and everything was working. Using the one I've got on my php and it hangs. I need to find out what my endpoint is.

Comment: @TomAlbanese protocol https and add this option and try again `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>1`

Answer (score 0):

To catch error in curl use

```
if($output === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

**Update**

For insecure `https` add below option in `curl`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
```

Comment: It's not getting any errors, it's just not getting a reply for some reason.